# Laravel, MYSQL full join workaround on two aggregated tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've got a table called `transactions` with below schema:

```
TRANSACTIONS
+----+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
| id | to (account_id) | from (account_id) | amount |
+----+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
| 1  | 1               | 3                 | 500    |
+----+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
| 2  | 2               | 1                 | 250    |
+----+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
| 3  | 1               | 2                 | 100    |
+----+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
| 4  | 4               | 2                 | 50     |
+----+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
```

`to` and `from` are foreign keys to `id` on table `accounts`.

I wanna get the `subtraction` of `sum` of `all received transactions` from `all paid transactions` of `selected accounts` as in the example accounts `1` and `2` and `all the accounts which whom those had transaction with`.

This is the desired result:

```
DESIRED QUERY RESULT
+---+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+
| # | account_id | totalReceived | totalPaid | balance |
+---+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+
| 1 | 1          | 600           | 250       | 350     |
+---+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+
| 2 | 2          | 250           | 150       | 100     |
+---+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+
| 3 | 3          | 0             | 500       | -500    |
+---+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+
| 4 | 4          | 50            | 0         | 50      |
+---+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+
```

What I've got so far:

as I'm using Laravel with query builder I run it like follows:

```
$k = [1, 2];

$receivedTransactions = DB::table('transactions as t1')->selectRaw('t1.to as account_id, sum(t1.amount) as totalReceived')
    ->whereIn('t1.from', $k)->orWhereIn('t1.to', $k)->groupBy('t1.to');

$paidTransactions = DB::table('transactions as t2')->selectRaw('t2.from as account_id, sum(t2.amount) as totalPaid')
    ->whereIn('t2.from', $k)->orWhereIn('t2.to', $k)->groupBy('t2.from');

$result = $receivedTransactions->leftJoinSub($paidTransactions, 't2', function ($join) {
    $join->on('t1.to', 't2.account_id');
})->selectRaw('totalPaid, (COALESCE(sum(t1.amount),0) - COALESCE(totalPaid,0)) as balance');
```

The big problem is it doesn't give me the 3rd row in the desired result table, because I don't have full join and I don't get the result from the right table which doesn't have corresponding row in the join so `null`.

this is what I get:

```
CURRENT QUERY RESULT
+---+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+
| # | account_id | totalReceived | totalPaid | balance |
+---+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+
| 1 | 1          | 600           | 250       | 350     |
+---+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+
| 2 | 2          | 250           | 150       | 100     |
+---+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+
| 4 | 4          | 50            | 0         | 50      |
+---+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+
```

I don't get the account_id `3` which was involved in giving account `1` the transaction no.1

Any help would be really appreciated. It doesn't matter if it is in Raw MYSQL format or laravel query builder. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you should use an outter join instead of left join because in receivedTransactions query you only are receiving 1,2 and 4 accounts, and you are joining only those three values, https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: @OmarAlvarado yup, but MYSQL doesnt support fulljoin nor fullouter join.

Comment: I didn't knew it, so, maybe you can just create a previous query with the union of all accounts in {from, to} columns and do the left join twice. SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT to FROM transactions
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT from FROM transactions) as base_accounts, I hope this helps

Comment: @OmarAlvarado Thanks for your comments yea the workaround is to use union but I cant figure out how to get the desired table result. I'll try it your way although I don't understand it fully but I'll do my best thanks for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this directly on mysql and after I tried to translate to Laravel syntax

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT base_accounts.account_id,
  COALESCE(t1.totalReceived, 0) as totalReceived,
  COALESCE(t2.totalPaid, 0) AS totalPaid,
  COALESCE(t1.totalReceived, 0) - COALESCE(t2.totalPaid, 0) as totalBalance
FROM (
     SELECT `to` as account_id FROM transactions UNION SELECT `from` FROM transactions
) as base_accounts
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT `to` as account_id, sum(amount) as totalReceived FROM transactions GROUP BY `to`
) as t1 on base_accounts.account_id = t1.account_id
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT `from` as account_id, sum(amount) as totalPaid FROM transactions GROUP BY `from`
) as t2 on base_accounts.account_id = t2.account_id
ORDER BY base_accounts.account_id
```

[image]

```
 \DB::table(\DB::raw('(SELECT `to` as account_id FROM transactions UNION SELECT `from` FROM transactions) as base_accounts'))
        ->select(DB::raw('
        DISTINCT base_accounts.account_id,
        COALESCE(t1.totalReceived, 0) as totalReceived,
        COALESCE(t2.totalPaid, 0) AS totalPaid,
        COALESCE(t1.totalReceived, 0) - COALESCE(t2.totalPaid, 0) as totalBalance
        '))
        ->leftJoin(
            \DB::raw('(SELECT `to` as account_id, sum(amount) as totalReceived FROM transactions GROUP BY `to`) as t1'),
            'base_accounts.account_id',
            '=',
            't1.account_id'
        )
        ->leftJoin(
            \DB::raw('(SELECT `from` as account_id, sum(amount) as totalPaid FROM transactions GROUP BY `from`) as t2'),
            'base_accounts.account_id',
            '=',
            't2.account_id'
        )->orderBy('base_accounts.account_id')->get();
```

I tested the query and worked fine.

Comment: Wow this is brilliant and it worked perfectly!Thank you very much and all the time you spent. one small thing I think you are doing it on the whole table, as I asked in the question, what If I wanna do it on for example only for accounts `1` and `2` but show the other accounts if the they had transactions with `1` or `2`. I had a `WhereIn` in my attempts. the result in this situations will be the same but if I have account `5` which has transactions with for example `6` it wouldn't be here in the result table. Thank you so much again.

Comment: And Thanks again for putting the time to convert it to Laravel query builder syntax. It's really appreciated.

Comment: I am glad to help :). I don't know if I am understanding very well, but maybe you need to add the where in inside second and third subquerys. For example for t1 you should add the WHERE like this:  (
         SELECT * FROM transactions
         WHERE `to` IN (1,2) OR `from` IN (1,2)

    ) as t1